# Fit titleLabel text of UIButton with autolayout on a fixed constant width

Tags: ios, swift

Hello guys I am trying to fit titleLable text on UIButton with autolayout fixed width constant. If text width is greater than the width constant then text should be truncate from trail and if text width less than the width constant then button width should be resize according to text.

Comment: use `<=`  parameter with width constraint

Comment: You want big text to truncate to new line?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this,

```
[self.myButton setTitle:@"this is the long title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.myButton.titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```

Convert in swift.

If you want that your button size is also increase then don't give fix width and if you want button size static and font size adjust according title length then give fix width constraint

Hope this will help :)